# SendMessage() only working when window is open, not when minimized

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I've been using `SendMessage` to send mouse clicks to a couple of windows. One being a game(everything works perfectly), but the other window, being a 3rd party tool for the game is having trouble with `SendMessage`. If the window is 'not minimized' everything works fine, don't matter if window is completely covered up by another. But if that same window is minimized then nothing happens, I checked with spy++ and the messages are indeed getting received but not being processed (correct term?). I've tried to solve this last couple days, doing both searches on here and Google alike, many of topics but nothing helped?

```
//MyImports
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

And this is how I have it wrapped

```
public static void LClick(string windowclass, int x, int y)
{
    IntPtr WHandle = FindWindow(windowclass, null);
    SendMessage(WHandle, (int)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)MakeLParam(x, y));
    SendMessage(WHandle, (int)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)MakeLParam(x, y));
}
```

I have tried focus, activate. One thing that might be useful info is that the third party program is being loaded as `module("Qt5QWindowIcon")` of the game.

I tried `PostMessage` as well, and it does the same thing as `SendMessage()` same problem when minimized.

This game does allow for macroing and unattended macroing, Hints the third part tool designed to execute the macros (published by the creators) I'm just trying to simulate a mouse click on the program to start the macro.

I would just use `SendInput`, but the entire purpose of my program is to run in background.

Comment: SendMessage works just fine with "minimized windows" since it doesn't actually need to be a window at all. It is probably that other application that for some reason stops pumping messages while minimized.

Comment: I've seen on more that one instance that an application disables controls during minimization--which means they probably don't handle certain messages while minimized.  If that's the case, I know of no way to get around that.

Comment: Can you control how the third party tool is opened?  If so, you could write a small service that opens it in the SYSTEM context so it has no visible UI, then you can run it maximized and send it whatever you want, without it ever displaying.

Comment: I take that back, The messages was being sent when minimized(promise) but looks to be now they are not. But still works when window is not minimized. I did do a few changes ill try to back up and and try to recreate the part that was sending messages when minimized.

Comment: FYI dont know why i didnt mention this earlier, the program is called UOSTEAM, In which you can find info about it from RunUO dot com. And to AresAvatar i understand the general ideal of what your saying, but how to go about doing something like that im clueless.

Comment: Let's use the Socratic method.  What is the size of a minimized window?  What happens when you click your mouse outside of a window?

Comment: @RichardP, here's an example of a small service: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample

Comment: Thanks for the replies,  ill read up on the service sample, because it is interesting. Sorry for being such a pain, but i dont like using code when i dont understand how it works, rhis is only for educational purposes, dont even play the game anymore (enjoyed learning something new). Just used it since it was a older game, didnt expect the 3rd party tool to be such a ninny.

Answer (score 1):

Couple years too late to answer this.... but here is something I discovered.

I have two apps:

- One that sends messages "Send App"
- One that receives messages "Receiving App". This is a on screen keyboard app that needs to hide until it is called. I don't want a taskbar icon showing for this.

The send app sends messages to the other using SendMessage. This is a watered down version of my code in my send app:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Receiving App");
IntPtr myMainWindowHandle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
IntPtr result = SendMessage(myMainWindowHandle , myMessage, myParameter, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This would work beautifully if the receiving app main window was open. If it was minimized (with showintaskbar = false) it would NOT receive the message.

After investigating further I confirmed the following details:

- GetProcesssesByName would return only one process ID (my receiving app checks to make sure a second instance isn't running when it starts)
- myMainWindowHandle was 0 if the receiving app was minimized.
- myMainWindowHandle was not 0 if the receiving app was open.

I did some debugging with both apps and was able to successfully get sendmessage to work when the following steps happened:

1. Open receiving app
2. Open send app
3. Pause code after the `IntPtr myMainWindowHandle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;`
4. Minimize the receiving app
5. Execute the `IntPtr result = SendMessage(myMainWindowHandle , myMessage, myParameter, IntPtr.Zero);`  code

In this scenario myMainWindowHandle is not zero and send message still works. This lead me to believe that the main process thread gives up the mainwindowhandle to some subthread that is still alive.

I found this piece of code on the web where you can get the main window handles for all threads in a process.

```
delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate   lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(int processId)
{
 var handles = new List<IntPtr>();

 foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads)
     EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id,
         (hWnd, lParam) => { handles.Add(hWnd); return true; }, IntPtr.Zero);

 return handles;
}
```

Sure enough, if I call it like this in my sending app

```
 foreach (IntPtr id in EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(processes[0].Id))
 {
    IntPtr result = SendMessage(id, myMessage, myParameter, IntPtr.Zero);
 }
```

My receiving app gets the message everytime, regardless of window state. Hope this helps someone else besides future me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be due to improper use of the handle, such as the value of hWnd being equal to MainWindowHandle or something else. MainWindowHandle seems to be effective only when the window is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

I 've faced **same problem** .Please change assembly name and project name (Changed name not started with name on that you are  throwing/posting windows message)then rebuild it and check it. Now you will able to debug.